# i want to use position right but does not work?

Tags: html, css

```html
  <html>
  <body>
    <style>
      div.relative {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid red;
        right:0;
      } 
      
      div.absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        right: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
      }
</style>
   </body>
</html>
```

In my code div relative I wrote right:0; but this box does not move in right corner and still is in left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working (if you add margin-left: auto). Other than that being relative right: 0 means moving right from *current* position. So no reason it would go to right edge. If it was absolute it would have.

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  i am relative
  <div class="absolute">
    i am absolute


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i want that red line box will be moved right

Comment: Yes I updated my answer. There are couple of ways to achieve that.